# How to hide label in viewModel with DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5, dispatch-queue

I have an issue, and got stuck. Don't know how to solve this.
There is a camera and some masks. When I open the camera and scroll to choose one of the masks, I want to show explanation how to use the camera with the masks, and these explanations after appearing should disappear in 3 seconds.

In viewController I have:

```
    maskExplanationLabel.configure(viewModel.maskExplanationLabel)
    viewModel.shouldShowMaskExplanation()
```

and in modelViewController I have:

```
var isCameraExplanationShown: Bool = false
var maskExplanationLabel: TextPresentable {
    TextViewModel(text: "camera.blank.explanation".localized(),
                  color: .white,
                  font: .montserratSemiBold(21),
                  isHidden: isCameraExplanationShown
    )
}
```

And a function which is in the placed in the right place:

```
func shouldShowMaskExplanation() {
    if isCameraExplanationShown {
        return
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.isCameraExplanationShown = true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it sets value to true, and explanation label should hide, but it hides only when choosing another mask.

I know the easy way would be to add dispatchQueue in viewController, but and this would work just fine, but don't want to "trash" viewController too much.
In swiftUI I would use @State, but how to do with UIKit?
Please help :) Thanks!